# NodeJS / discord.js: Read all files in the folders of a specific directory

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that I'm coding, and one thing I'm doing with it is separating all commands into subfolders based on the category they're in *(Utility, System, etc)*.

The issue I'm having is that I'm unsure of how to find all the folders in the `/commands` directory, then read all the files from all these folders. I've already specified to read all the folders inside the directory, now I need all the subfolders (and files in them) to be read.

Can I get some help on this? Thanks in advance!

---

[EDIT: addresses comment from initial post] Here's the current code I have, which currently just loads all the files it finds in the base directories (and not subfolders):

```js
const init = async () => {
  const cmdFiles = await readdir("commands");
  client.logger.log(`Loading a total of ${cmdFiles.length} commands.`);
  cmdFiles.forEach(f => {
    if (!f.endsWith(".js")) return;
    const response = client.loadCommand(f);
    if (response) console.log(response);
  });

  const evtFiles = await readdir("./events/");
  client.logger.log(`Loading a total of ${evtFiles.length} events.`);
  evtFiles.forEach(file => {
    const eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.logger.log(`Loading Event: ${eventName}`);
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });

  client.levelCache = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < client.config.permLevels.length; i++) {
    const thisLevel = client.config.permLevels[i];
    client.levelCache[thisLevel.name] = thisLevel.level;
  }

  client.login(client.config.token);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using "javascript" to read local files? Do you have any code that you could post to clarify your problem?

Comment: NodeJS might be what you mean. You can use JavaScript as a general purpose language with Node. In that case, you can use the native file system module. See the docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: @JacobPenney I just updated the title and tags to reflect what I'm using. Plus, I've added some code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to read recursive?

Make a crawl function like this:

```
async function crawl(directory, filesArray) {
    const dirs = await fsPromises.readdir(directory, {
        withFileTypes: true 
    });

    //loop through all files/directories
    for (let i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
        const currentDir = dirs[i];
        const newPath = path.join(directory, currentDir.name);
         if (currentDir.isDirectory()) {
             //if directory crawl again.
             await crawl(newPath, filesArray);
         }
         else {
             //if it is a file append it to the array
             filesArray.push(newPath);
         }
    }
}
```

Get all files in directory & subdirectories:

```
const init = async () => {
    let cmdFiles = []; // create empty array and pass it into the crawl function
    await crawl(baseDirectory, cmdFiles);
    // now cmdFiles array has all the files in directory & subdirectories.
};
```

Off course don't forget to import fs:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
```

I hope this helped, if not please comment & I will change the answer.

Comment: Whenever I try to use `crawl()`, I get a ReferenceError. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot extensions there, I changed the answer. Is it resolved now. Is there something else in the error?

Comment: All it says is that “crawl” is not defined.

Comment: Did you create the crawl function as above?

Comment: Oh! I never did that. I’ll put that function at the top of the block in my original post. Where should the second block — starting with `const init` — be located?

Comment: the init function is just an example. Just use the crawl function in your original code to get all files in a folder & subfolders.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I’ll update this thread if anything else is needed.

Comment: I attempted to use it, but now `fsPromises` isn't defined...what should I do?

Comment: Import fs and get promises like this: const fsPromises = require('fs').promises; I will add this to the answer

Comment: It works! I just added a line showing that your answer worked. Thanks for the help! (-:

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like **Laurent** got the answer!

What I had to do was create the crawl function (which looks for all the files in a directory and its subdirectories), then set it to an array to be called later.

Thanks for the help, **Laurent**! I've marked your response as the answer to this question.